# How to commit the multiple transactions from different users using concurrency in windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Any one give me idea behind for committing the multiple transactions at  a time in windows 8.
i.e by using concurrency need to commit all transactions at a time .is it possible ?if ok then please give me idea for implementation in windows 8.

EDIT:

Mulitple transactions are coming from different users at same time then i need to commit all these transactions at a time to server.in windows 8 there is concurrency update mechanism.like that i need to commit all those to server.please tell me idea on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Where are those transactions committed? On the server or in the app? Do you want all transactions to be committed together? Where do they come from?

Comment: need to commit all the transactions in database server not in app.all transactions need to commit together at same time no time difference  ?all requests  are coming from different users at same time.

Comment: Do the apps contact the database server directly (as in - open a connection to the database), or is there a server in the middle?

Comment: directly to server only no middle servers behind.

Comment: You should update your question to make it clear.

Comment: some of guys telling in windows 8 directly OS itself doing the task scheduling and resource allocation.any idea?

Comment: Oh, and what is this 'concurrency update' you speak of?

Comment: concurrency update is an singleton instance lock the resource and share that resource to all processes at same time.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd504870.aspx

Comment: Are all your user apps running on the same machine?

Comment: It is polite to mark the correct/best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a database server accepting connections from various clients, and you want to synchronize them so that they are all treated as one big database transaction. I don't think this can be done in a straightforward fashion.

You need your clients to save their data to an intermediary place (say, an "about-to-be-saved" table), and then once in a while, depending on what you define as 'at once', move data from the intermediate table to the "really-saved" table.

You could implement this transaition from about-to-be-saved to really-saved inside your database, so you don't need an additional server.

Keep in mind, though, that giving multiple clients direct access to your database is almost never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is tricky. Your question title makes this sound like a database question. Of course without ADO.Net in Windows 8, transactions don't come up a lot in forums. But what you want is the request of multiple users to be processed as a single, atomic action.

Let's see. There are lots of ways to do this. But let's pretend you have a service with two methods. AddToQueue(request) and CheckStatus(request). These two methods would virtually create a transaction for you. Something like this:

**Scenario 1 (nothing goes wrong)**

1. User A uses AddToQueue(), adding his request to add $1 to bank
2. User B uses AddToQueue(), adding his request to add $2 to bank
3. User A uses CheckStatus(), to see if his request is complete, it is PENDING
4. User C uses AddToQueue(), adding his request to add $1 to bank

> Let's pretend that three items in the queue triggers the transaction to occur

1. The system batches the 3 existing requests, executing in a transaction
2. The system flags the requests as SUCCESS
3. User A uses CheckStatus(), to see if his request is complete, it is SUCCESS
4. User B uses CheckStatus(), to see if his request is complete, it is SUCCESS
5. User C uses CheckStatus(), to see if his request is complete, it is SUCCESS

**Scenario 2 (something goes wrong)**

1. User A uses AddToQueue(), adding his request to add $1 to bank
2. User B uses AddToQueue(), adding his request to add $2 to bank
3. User A uses CheckStatus(), to see if his request is complete, it is PENDING
4. User C uses AddToQueue(), adding his request to add $1 to bank

> Let's pretend that three items in the queue triggers the transaction to occur

1. The system batches the 3 existing requests, executing in a transaction
2. The system flags the requests as FAIL (for whatever reason)
3. User A uses CheckStatus(), to see if his request is complete, it is FAIL
4. User A retries using AddToQueue()
5. User B uses CheckStatus(), to see if his request is complete, it is FAIL
6. User B does NOT retry
7. User C uses CheckStatus(), to see if his request is complete, it is FAIL
8. User C retries using AddToQueue()
9. User D uses AddToQueue(), adding his request to add $1 to bank

> Let's pretend that three items in the queue triggers the transaction to occur

1. The system batches the 3 existing requests, executing in a transaction
2. The system flags the requests as SUCCESS
3. User A uses CheckStatus(), to see if his request is complete, it is SUCCESS
4. User B is no longer active in this scenario!
5. User C uses CheckStatus(), to see if his request is complete, it is SUCCESS
6. User D uses CheckStatus(), to see if his request is complete, it is SUCCESS

Make sense? That will work just fine.

Of course, there is more to think through. But that's the basics of it.

Best of luck!